# Mule - testing a flow that has an inbound/outbound endpoint with a Mule property as the file path

Tags: java, testing, properties, mule, filepath

I'm trying to write a test for a Mule flow that will involve dropping a file in a location, waiting for it to be processed by my flow and compare the output to see if it has been transformed correctly. My flow looks as follows:

```
<flow name="mainFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <file:inbound-endpoint name="fileIn" path="${inboundPath}">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="myFile.csv" caseSensitive="true"/> 
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    ...

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outboundPath}" outputPattern="out.csv"/>
</flow>
```

Is there a way I can access the `inboundPath` and `outboundPath` Mule properties inside of my test class so that I can drop files and wait for output in the correct places?

The test class I'm using is:

```
public class MappingTest extends BaseFileToFileFunctionalTest {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "mappingtest.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapping() throws Exception {
        dropInputFileIntoPlace("myFile.csv");
        waitForOutputFile("out.csv", 100);

        assertEquals(getExpectedOutputFile("expected-out.csv"), getActualOutputFile("out.csv"));
    }

}
```

Which extends this class:

```
public abstract class BaseFileToFileFunctionalTest extends FunctionalTestCase {
    private static final File INPUT_DIR = new File("/tmp/muletest/input");
    private static final File OUTPUT_DIR = new File("/tmp/muletest/output");
    private static final Charset CHARSET = Charsets.UTF_8;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        new File("/tmp/muletest/input").mkdirs();
        new File("/tmp/muletest/output").mkdirs();

        empty(INPUT_DIR);
        empty(OUTPUT_DIR);

    }

    private void empty(File inputDir) {
        for (File file : inputDir.listFiles()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    protected File waitForOutputFile(String expectedFileName, int retryAttempts) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean polling = true;
        int attemptsRemaining = retryAttempts;
        File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT_DIR, expectedFileName);

        while (polling) {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
            if (outputFile.exists()) {
                polling = false;
            }
            if (attemptsRemaining == 0) {
                VisibleAssertions.fail("Output file did not appear within expected time");
            }
            attemptsRemaining--;
        }
        outputFile.deleteOnExit();

        return outputFile;
    }

    protected void dropInputFileIntoPlace(String inputFileResourceName) throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File(INPUT_DIR, inputFileResourceName);
        Files.copy(Resources.newInputStreamSupplier(Resources.getResource(inputFileResourceName)), inputFile);
        inputFile.deleteOnExit();
    }

    protected String getActualOutputFile(String outputFileName) throws IOException {
        File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT_DIR, outputFileName);
        return Files.toString(outputFile, CHARSET);
    }

    protected String getExpectedOutputFile(String resourceName) throws IOException {
        return Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(resourceName), CHARSET);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm currently creating temporary input/output directories. I'd like to make this part read from the Mule properties if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you load your config files you should have been loading these properties files as well. So they should be available in your flow inbound and outbound endpoints.

Comment: So my question is around how I can access these from **within my Java class**? As I specify where to drop the test files, and where to poll for output

Comment: Add the testcase class code sample to understand what approach you are using to load the flow configs. This will help in providing the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After observing your test classes and code I could see that you want to dynamically create temp folders place files in them. And the flow should read the files from Temp Directory and write output to another Temp directory. Point to be noted is that Mule's Endpoints are created when the configuration is loaded. So the ${inbound} and ${outbound} should be provided to the mule flow by the time they are provided.

1. So one option can be to create a dummy flow pointing to the temp folders for testing.
   or
2. Create a test properties file pointing to the temp folders and load that to your flow config, so that your flow endpoints will get the temp folder paths.

In any way path cannot be provided to the flow inbound endpoints after they have been created(on config load).

**Update1:**
As per your comment the solution with option would be like the following.

1. Seperate the properties loading part of the config into another config.
   Like "mapping-core-config.xml,mappingtest.xml" where the mapping-core-config will have the tags to load the properties file.
2. Now create a test config file for the mapping-core-config.xml file which loads the test properties file. This should be used in your test config. This way without modifying or disturbing your main code, you can test your flows pointing to temp folders.

   "mapping-core-test-config.xml,mappingtest.xml"

Note: The test config can reside in the src/test/resources folders.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given that this process will be re-used for a number of flows I think the first option will create an unnecessary number of dummy flows - so looks like the second option is the one to go with here. Would you be able to provide an example of how I'd load a test properties file? Or is it simply a case of replacing: `return "mappingtest.xml";` in my `MappingTest` class with `return "mappingtest.xml,test.properties";` and then populating `test.properties` with the temp folder paths?

Comment: Thank you for the update @user1760178 - this has worked perfectly! Appreciate the help.